# Compare Same and Different in Two Columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small dataframe, like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# data's stored in dictionary
details = {
    'address_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'business': ['verizon', 'verizon', 'comcast', 'sprint', 'att']
}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
 

print(df)
```

[image]

I am trying to find out if, and when a person switched to a different cell phone service.

I tried this logic; didn't work.

```
df['new'] = df.Column1.isin(df.Column1) & df[~df.Column2.isin(df.Column2)]
```

Basically, given index row 0 and row 1, when the address_id was the same, the business was the same, but the business changed from verizon to comcast in index row 2. Also, given index row 3 and row 4, the address_id was the same, but the business changed from sprint to att in index row 4. I'd like to add a new column to the dataframe to flag these changes. How can I do that?

Comment: What would you like the contents of this column to be? And can the `business` column have a limited number of values that can be represented as an `Enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: A comment by @rickhg12hs points out that my earlier answers (see below), while detecting when a person switches to a new cell phone service, do not handle the case of a person switching back to a previous service.

To handle this possibility, we must use something like the logic in another answer (@Pranav Hosangadi), though I would do it slightly differently:

```py
df['new'] = ( df
    .groupby('address_id', sort=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x.business != x.business.shift().bfill())
    .reset_index(0).business )
```

Input:

```
   address_id business
0           1  verizon
1           1  verizon
2           1  comcast
3           2   sprint
4           2      att
5           2   sprint
```

Output:

```
   address_id business    new
0           1  verizon  False
1           1  verizon  False
2           1  comcast   True
3           2   sprint  False
4           2      att   True
5           2   sprint   True
```

**Performance comparison**:
Here is test code for 600k rows and 5 columns, with results showing that `PREVIOUS UPDATE` takes about 0.1 seconds to identify 333815 rows for which `new==True`, while `UPDATE` takes about 35 seconds to find 335334 `True` rows, reflecting about 0.5% additional rows for which a person has switched cell phone services and then switched back.

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
details = {
'address_id': rng.integers(1,100_000, size=600_000),
'business': [['verizon','comcast','sprint','att'][i] for i in rng.integers(0,3, size=600_000)],
'foo': 1,
'bar': 2
}
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
 
print('groupby() ...')
start = datetime.now()
x = ( df
    .groupby('address_id', sort=False) )
print(f'... complete after {datetime.now() - start} time elapsed.')

print('apply() ...')
start = datetime.now()
x = ( x
    .apply(lambda x: x.business != x.business.shift().bfill()) )
print(f'... complete after {datetime.now() - start} time elapsed.')

print('reset_index() ...')
start = datetime.now()
df['new'] = ( x
    .reset_index(0).business )
print(f'... complete after {datetime.now() - start} time elapsed.')

print(df)
print('rows with "new" == True', df.new.sum())

df = pd.DataFrame(details)
print('PREVIOUS UPDATE() ...')
start = datetime.now()
df['new'] = df.address_id.map(df.groupby('address_id').first().business) != df.business
print(f'... complete after {datetime.now() - start} time elapsed.')
print('rows with "new" == True', df.new.sum())
```

Results:

```
groupby() ...
... complete after 0:00:00 time elapsed.
apply() ...
... complete after 0:00:33.541322 time elapsed.
reset_index() ...
... complete after 0:00:00.040942 time elapsed.
        address_id business  foo  bar    new
0            20223   sprint    1    2  False
1            29297  comcast    1    2  False
2            92489  comcast    1    2  False
3            29297  verizon    1    2   True
4            98901  comcast    1    2  False
...            ...      ...  ...  ...    ...
599995       29823  comcast    1    2   True
599996       39328  comcast    1    2   True
599997       27594  comcast    1    2  False
599998       14903   sprint    1    2   True
599999       87375  verizon    1    2   True

[600000 rows x 5 columns]
rows with "new" == True 335334

PREVIOUS UPDATE() ...
... complete after 0:00:00.097930 time elapsed.
rows with "new" == True 333815
```

**PREVIOUS UPDATE**: Here is an even simpler way than my original answer using `join()` (see below) to do what your question asks:

```py
df['new'] = df.address_id.map(df.groupby('address_id').first().business) != df.business
```

Explanation:

- Use `groupby()` and `first()` to create a dataframe whose `business` column contains the first one encountered for each `address_id`
- Use `Series.map()` to transform the original dataframe's `address_id` column into this first `business` value
- Add column `new` which is `True` only if this new `business` differs from the original `business` column.

---

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION**:

Here is a simple way to do what you've asked using `groupby()` and `join()`:

```py
df = df.join(df.groupby('address_id').first(), on='address_id', rsuffix='_first')
df = df.assign(new=df.business != df.business_first).drop(columns='business_first')f
```

Output:

```
   address_id business    new
0           1  verizon  False
1           1  verizon  False
2           1  comcast   True
3           2   sprint  False
4           2      att   True
```

Explanation:

- Use `groupby()` and `first()` to create a dataframe whose `business` column contains the first one encountered for each `address_id`
- Use `join()` to add a column `business_first` to `df` containing the corresponding first business for each `address_id`
- Use `assign()` to add a column `new` containing a boolean indicating whether the row contains a new `business` with an existing `address_id`
- Use `drop()` to eliminate the `business_first` column.

Comment: What about the case where an `address_id` switches back to the first `business` from the second?  For example, after `df = pd.concat([df, df.iloc[[0]]],  ignore_index=True)`, `df["new"] = ...` doesn't catch the switch back.

Comment: @rickhg12hs See my updated answer.

Comment: The 'update' seems wicked slow, compared to the 'previous update'. The first finished in about a couple seconds and the second has been running for 30+ minutes. Is that normal? I'm analyzing a dataframe of 600k records and 4 columns.

Comment: See my updated answer. It takes me about 35 seconds to run 600k rows.

Answer (score 1):

First, `groupby` on `address_id`.

```
groups = df.groupby("address_id")
```

Then, iterate over the groups, and find where the value of `business` changes:

```
for address_id, grp_data in groups:
    changed = grp_data['business'].ne(grp_data['business'].shift().bfill())
   
    df.loc[grp_data.index, "changed"] = changed
```

`.shift().bfill()` shifts all data one index over (`0 -> 1`, `1 -> 2`, and so on), and then backfills the first value. For example:

```
>>> df["business"]
0    verizon
1    verizon
2    comcast
3     sprint
4        att
Name: business, dtype: object

>>> df["business"].shift()
0        NaN
1    verizon
2    verizon
3    comcast
4     sprint
Name: business, dtype: object

>>> df["business"].shift().bfill()
0    verizon
1    verizon
2    verizon
3    comcast
4     sprint
Name: business, dtype: object
```

Running the loop makes the following dataframe:

```
   address_id business changed
0           1  verizon   False
1           1  verizon   False
2           1  comcast    True
3           2   sprint   False
4           2      att    True
```